# How to stop and restart Audio Service using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I made a batch file with the following line

```
net stop audiosrv & net start audiosrv
```

It just flashes and closes, not actually doing the command. I think I saw something about administrator privileges in the command window but it flashed too fast to tell. What is wrong?

Comment: add a `pause` statement, either as a new line or append `&pause` to your existing. You will then be able to read the message. In all probability, you need to run the command with administrator privilege. Try right-clicking and select "Run as administrator"

Comment: run as admin worked. thanks

Comment: @LazerWing for what it's worth, I created a batch file for this here: https://gist.github.com/tigerhawkvok/b27b0cbaca2deda1ae33 / [SuperUser answer](http://superuser.com/a/1048835/566941)

Answer (score 7):

Create a new text file.
Then, paste the following code into it.

```
@echo off     
net stop audiosrv    
pause    
net start audiosrv    
pause
```

Save the file as a bat file.
Open the bat file as admin.

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: I have noticed that if you have fx. "Lenovo Hotkey Client Loader", then trying to stop windows audio will result in a pop-up dialog asking for confirmation to stop other services -- any chance you know how to force them to stop ?

Answer (score 4):

Here find a script for running a batch file as an admin

```
@echo off  

if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)   
net stop audiosrv    
pause    
net start audiosrv    
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

A more comprehensive batch file approach:

```
@echo off  

if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)   
net stop audiosrv    
pause    
net stop AudioEndpointBuilder
pause    
net start AudioEndpointBuilder
pause    
net start audiosrv    
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

The audio service is started by Windows using local system account and therefore it is not possible to stop this service without administrator privileges as command `net` outputs.

The solution is clicking with right (secondary) mouse button on batch file and click with left (primary) mouse button in context menu on **Run as Administrator** as [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo) already suggested before.

For testing a batch file just created, it is always useful to open a command prompt window and run the batch file from within this window by entering name (with path if needed) and hitting RETURN. A shortcut for opening a command prompt window can be found in Accessories menu of Windows start menu, or the command `cmd.exe` is executed which also opens a console window.